# vbasic 2008 updating data in underlying table

Tags: vb.net

When I try to update data in a database, the dataset gets updated but not the underlying table
could the fact that I am using 64 bit system be a problem?

```
Public Class Form1
  Private Sub PlayersBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PlayersBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click 
    Me.Validate()
    Me.PlayersBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.DataSet)     
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Could be anything - we need more information to help you. Please post code, explain your design etc.

Comment: code for table save icon below

Comment: Public Class Form1

    Private Sub PlayersBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PlayersBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
        Me.Validate()
        Me.PlayersBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.DataSet)

    End Sub